# How to integrate amcharts and Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to integrate ember.js and amcharts. I've created following view based on code from live chart editor (http://pastebin.com/XWVWkhJk)

```
App.AmchartView = Ember.View.extend
    classNames: ['amcharts']
    series: []
    config: {}

    didInsertElement: ->
        @renderGraph()

    renderGraph: (->
        AmCharts.makeChart @get('elementId'),
            type: "serial"
            pathToImages: "http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/"
            categoryField: "date"
            dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD"
            categoryAxis:
                parseDates: true
            chartCursor: {}
            chartScrollbar: {}
            trendLines: []
            graphs: [
                {
                    bullet: "round"
                    id: "AmGraph-1"
                    title: "graph 1"
                    valueField: "column-1"
                }
                {
                    bullet: "square"
                    id: "AmGraph-2"
                    title: "graph 2"
                    valueField: "column-2"
                }
            ]
            guides: []
            valueAxes: [
                id: "ValueAxis-1"
                title: "Axis title"
            ]
            allLabels: []
            balloon: {}
            legend:
                useGraphSettings: true

            titles: [
                id: "Title-1"
                size: 15
                text: "Chart Title"
            ]
            dataProvider: [
                {
                    date: "2014-03-01"
                    "column-1": 8
                    "column-2": 5
                }
                {
                    date: "2014-03-02"
                    "column-1": 6
                    "column-2": 7
                }
                {
                    date: "2014-03-03"
                    "column-1": 2
                    "column-2": 3
                }
                {
                    date: "2014-03-04"
                    "column-1": 1
                    "column-2": 3
                }
                {
                    date: "2014-03-05"
                    "column-1": 2
                    "column-2": 1
                }
                {
                    date: "2014-03-06"
                    "column-1": 3
                    "column-2": 2
                }
                {
                    date: "2014-03-07"
                    "column-1": 6
                    "column-2": 8
                }
            ]
    ).observes('series', 'config')
```

Inside the view I can see amcharts divs but graph is not rendering. What's wrong? I have all the amcharts files included in `<link>` tag and there is not any error in browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you might be missing here.  If you included a jsbin or jsfiddle instead of just the view file, it would be much easier to guess what might be going wrong.

For one thing, I don't know what your template file looks like, so I don't know how you're injecting this chart.

I've been able to successfully make an amchart using an Ember view in [this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kexamedo/3/edit).

If you can post more of your code, I'd be happy to help isolate what's going wrong, I know SO is supposed to be more showing the why than the how, but there just isn't enough info here.

Comment: The thing was that I didn't set `width` and `height` attribute for chart in CSS. Thank you very much for your time.